# Why do I get an error when using Timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timestamp

the snippet below generates an error, and I don't understand what is wrong nor how to correct it:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import datetime

dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(Timestamp("1900-01-01"))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13616\1174166552.py in <module>
      3 import datetime
      4 
----> 5 dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(pd.Timestamp("1900-01-01"))

TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)
```

What does it mean that `an integer is required`?

Could you point out to me what I didn't understand about using Timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

[datetime.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) expects Unix time in seconds as input, i.e. a number. And no @ChatGPT, it does **not** have to be an integer, float works fine. A [pandas.Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html) is a data type, not a number. EX:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
import pandas as pd

print(datetime.fromtimestamp(86400.0, tz=timezone.utc))
# 1970-01-02 00:00:00+00:00

print(pd.Timestamp("now", tz="UTC"))
# 2023-03-25 08:43:14.811598+00:00

print(repr(pd.Timestamp("now", tz="UTC")))
# Timestamp('2023-03-25 08:43:14.811766+0000', tz='UTC')
```

Just as you can create pandas Timestamp objects from strings, you can create them from time since the epoch, but you need to specify the unit

```py
print(pd.Timestamp(86400.0, unit="s", tz="UTC"))
# 1970-01-02 00:00:00+00:00
```

Note: I'm setting UTC here explicitly to avoid confusion if you run this on other machines. Python datetime otherwise resembles local time as set on that machine.